# use shell script parameter as input for in-script call to a program

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, command

I have a shell script (run.sh) that takes 3 parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR1=$1
VAR2=$2
VAR3=$3

grep -Pzl "$VAR1(\n|.)*$VAR2(\n|.)*$VAR3" * | xargs -L1 cat
```

the script should take parameter 1, 2, 3 and pass it to grep, to make it run the script like:

```
./run.sh a b c
```

and I want it to be interpreted as

```
grep -Pzl "A(\n|.)*B(\n|.)*C" * | xargs -L1 cat
```

But it seems like it didn't evaluate my parameters as the command's parameter to swap the variables in-line.

I have no problems with the grep condition, but rather, the grep command's variables are being treated as-is, and it's not being "interpreted" as what it contains.

Comment: You're passing lower case `a b c` but your desired result contains capitals. Does changing the case of the arguments help?

Comment: if you don't care about the case you can use the -i grep option

Comment: "*didn't evaluate my parameters*" Run the script as `bash -x run.sh a b c` which will show you the `grep` command after the expansions.

Comment: @cdarke Thanks for the suggestion, but what I meant by "not evaluating my parameters" is that, i want it when the shell script runs, the command will be executed as-is, which means, the $VAR1 is not being swapped as "a" in-line.

Comment: What do you mean by "in-line"?

Answer (score -1):

The shell replaces all \n characters by a newline. Therefore, your pattern does not work.

If you want to match a literal backslash, followed by the letter n, you need to write `\\n`.

**UPDATE**: This applies to zsh, but not to bash.

Comment: "*The shell replaces all \n characters by a newline*" Not in my version.  `echo "\nhello\n"` gives `\nhello\n`.  You need `echo $'\nhello\n'` to get the shell to interpolate (or in this case  `echo -e`).

Comment: Oops, only zsh is doing this. I should have checked it before with bash ... thought they would behave the same. I will update my comment.